# Use of Scope_Identity with OUTPUT clause for Audit Table

Tags: sql, t-sql, stored-procedures

I am using one stored procedure to do insert to main table, and then use OUTPUT to insert in audit table as well, and use `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` to get the id of the record that was added to the main table. But the issue if that `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` return the id of what was added to Audit instead of main table.

The code below shows my SP:

```
BEGIN TRY
Insert into [Client](
    Name,
    Disabled, 
    CreatedBy, 
    CreatedOn) 

    OUTPUT  inserted.ClientID, inserted.[Name], inserted.[Disabled], 
            inserted.CreatedBy, inserted.CreatedOn
    INTO [Audit].[Client]
values(
    @Name, 
    @Disabled, 
    @CreatedBy, 
    SYSDATETIME())


Set @ID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

END TRY

return  @ID
```

Any help of how I can get the id of record that was added to the client table instead of Client Audit table?

Thanks

Comment: You are using the `OUTPUT` clause.  Why are you using `SCOPE_IDENTIFY()`.  I do't understand.

Comment: OUTPUT Clause is used to insert into Audit table, SCOPE_IDENTIFY() is used so i can the ID of what was inserted to our main table

Comment: Why not have the Audit table have the same identity value from the original table I wonder? There's not need to have the Audit table have its own identity column. Btw, the answer by @TapakahUa has potential problems, read the link I commented on that answer.

Comment: well i dont have any control over design of the database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use you OUTPUT value(if you do not have instead of trigger on clients) or

```
Set @ID = IDENT_CURRENT ('Client')
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/ident-current-transact-sql

Comment: Thanks this works , i was doing,  set @ID = (SELECT MAX(ClientID) from [Client]) to get the ID but IDENT_CURRENT look better

Comment: Please read this: [**For the last time, NO, you can't trust IDENT_CURRENT()**](https://sqlperformance.com/2014/01/t-sql-queries/ident-current). TL;DR (conclusion of the link): _Just don't use it. For anything. Ever. By the time you read the value, it could already be wrong._

Comment: Enough read first row msdn  @The last identity value generated can be for any session and any scope.@